# delete surrounding eruby tag in rails

Tags: plugin-vim-surround

When adding a new pair of eruby tag like `<%= %>` surrounding `Time.now`, just type below keys:

<kbd>y</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>=</kbd>

It does the job `<%= *Time.now %>`. I have no idea how to do the opposite by removing it without using 'undo'.

[Here](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround/pull/107/files) it is probably the fix, but how to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the following in your `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/eruby.vim` file:

```
nmap <buffer> ds= ds<ds%dw
```

The idea is we delete each surrounding in turn. First `<` then `%`. Next we remove the `=` and the extra space.

Comment: I created a new file erb.vim as you mentioned, then open an erb file, tried `ds=`, it didn't work. What might be wrong?

Comment: @canoe There are 2 problems. 1) I had a typo in the mapping, It should be `nmap` instead of `nnmap`. 2) The `'filetype'` for *.erb files is `eruby` not `erb`. So you will need to name your file: `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/eruby.vim`

Comment: Would this mapping be better to use `nnoremap` instead? It's my understanding set up mappings this way to make sure they don't create recursive issues. In this case, I doubt it will be used elsewhere and it's good to be aware anyway.

Comment: @Shadoath, you are correct `nnoremap` would be preferred method. However, we are relying on [surround.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) to do the `ds<` and `ds%`, so using `nmap` makes this easy